# Error in running a function to convert coordinates in degrees to decimal for EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

Currently I am working on VBA excel to create a widget to verify coordinates whether it lies under the radius of ANOTHER predefined and pre-specified sets of coordinates.

In the module, I want to convert the coordinates from degrees to decimal before doing the calculation - as the formula of the calculation only allow the decimal form of coordinates.

However, each and every time I want to run the macros this error (Run-time error '5', invalid procedure call or argument) will appear. Then, the debug button will bring me to below line of coding:

```
 degrees = Val(Left(Degree_Deg, InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "°") - 1))
```

For your information, the full function is as below:

```
Function Convert_Decimal(Degree_Deg As String) As Double
'source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213449

   Dim degrees As Double
   Dim minutes As Double
   Dim seconds As Double

   Degree_Deg = Replace(Degree_Deg, "~", "°")


   degrees = Val(Left(Degree_Deg, InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "°") - 1))

   minutes = Val(Mid(Degree_Deg, InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "°") + 2, _
             InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "'") - InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "°") - 2)) / 60

   seconds = Val(Mid(Degree_Deg, InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "'") + _
           2, Len(Degree_Deg) - InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "'") - 2)) / 3600

   Convert_Decimal = degrees + minutes + seconds

End Function
```

Thank you.

Your kind assistance and attention in this matter are highly appreciated.

Regards,

Nina.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a String to a Double, you do NOT use `Val()`.  Instead you should use `CDbl()`.  See [this Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx) for more details.

Edit:  There are also some small errors with your formulas.  The below code should work:

```
Function Convert_Decimal(Degree_Deg As String) As Double
'source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213449

   Dim degrees As Double
   Dim minutes As Double
   Dim seconds As Double

   Degree_Deg = Replace(Degree_Deg, "~", "°")


   degrees = CDbl(Left(Degree_Deg, InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "°") - 1))

   minutes = CDbl(Mid(Degree_Deg, InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "°") + 1, _
             InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "'") - InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "°") - 1)) / 60

   seconds = CDbl(Mid(Degree_Deg, InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "'") + _
           1, Len(Degree_Deg) - InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "'") - 1)) / 3600

   Convert_Decimal = degrees + minutes + seconds

End Function
```

Comment: Dear Mr Christmas, I have tried your posted code above. However, there is run-time error '13' : type mismatch at line : seconds = CDbl(Mid(Degree_Deg, InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "'") + _
           1, Len(Degree_Deg) - InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "'") - 1)) / 3600.  For your info, it's not only code that I use in the widget. Besides, I'm not really sure whether the error is coming from the coding or from the data in the worksheet. I hope I can share the workbook here so you can have overall idea on how the widget looks like. cc:@Chrismas007

Comment: What characters are at the end of the string?  My code assumes that you have ONE character at the end of the string after the number that being a `"` but if you have multiple characters like two hashes `''` then this is one digit off.